# how to handle the parameter with special url characters when using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Now I want to use sed to replace the url from a file, this is the original file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /api/test {
        proxy_connect_timeout 3000;
        proxy_send_timeout 3000;
        proxy_read_timeout 3000;
        send_timeout 3000;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
        client_body_buffer_size 100M;
proxy_pass:www.baidu.com
    }

    location /api/demo {
        proxy_connect_timeout 3000;
        proxy_send_timeout 3000;
        proxy_read_timeout 3000;
        send_timeout 3000;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
        client_body_buffer_size 100M;
proxy_pass:www.google.com
    }
}
```

and this is the replace shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -u

set -e

set -x

echo "please input url1:"

read URL1

echo "$URL1"

echo "plase input url2:"

read URL2

echo "$URL2"


sed -E -in-place "12s/.*proxy\_pass.*/proxy\_pass:$URL1/" nginx.conf

sed -E -in-place "22s/.*proxy\_pass.*/proxy\_pass:$URL2/" nginx.conf
```

this script works fine, but when I input the url with http like this format: `http::/www.google.com`, the script shows error like this:

```
+ sed -E -in-place '12s?.*proxy\_pass.*/proxy\_pass:http::/www.google.com?' nginx.conf
sed: 1: "12s?.*proxy\_pass.*/pro ...": unterminated substitute in regular expression
```

what should I do to make the sed works with special charactors?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a different delimiter to the `s` command instead of `/`:

```
sed -E -in-place "12s|.*proxy_pass.*|proxy_pass:$URL1|" nginx.conf
```

assuming your URL can't contain `|`. Beware that the URL must still not contain `&`, which is a legal URL character, but has a special meaning in `sed` replacements.

I also removed the backslashes before the underscores, because `\_` is undefined and could produce strange results in some `sed` implementations.

Finally, you may consider adding a semicolon after the URLs in the replacement, so the URLs do not need to contain them:

```
sed -E -in-place "12s|.*proxy_pass.*|proxy_pass:$URL1;|" nginx.conf
```